# How to Local Bert to Bert_module_hub

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, nlp, bert-language-model

I just want to my **Local Bert** to here:

> bert_module = hub.Module(
> **BERT_MODEL_HUB**,
> trainable=True)

How to add my local bert?
i have Tensorflow==1.15 and python==3.7

```
def create_model(is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels,
                 num_labels):
  
  bert_module = hub.Module(
      BERT_MODEL_HUB,
      trainable=True)
  bert_inputs = dict(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      input_mask=input_mask,
      segment_ids=segment_ids)
  bert_outputs = bert_module(
      inputs=bert_inputs,
      signature="tokens",
      as_dict=True)
```